# NullPointerException In my widgets inside a Fragment

Tags: java, android, null, butterknife

When the method(Bill) is called the widgets that I initialized with Butterknife is returning null(noPrev and recyclerList).

In other classes like activities, I used the same method(Binding the widget with BUtterknife) and It is working well but when I tried binding my widgets inside the fragment, it always returning null.
........................................................................

```
public class Home extends Fragment implements BridgeInterface.BillsResponse{


@BindView(R.id.rvBillList)
RecyclerView recyclerList;

@BindView(R.id.tvNoPreviousBill)
TextView noPrev;

public List<Bill> list_of_bill = new ArrayList<>();
private BillRecyclerAdapter adapter;
private Handler h;
private Runnable r;
private View v;

public Home() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static Home getInstance() {
    Home home = new Home();
    return home;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(Home.this,v);
    if(list_of_bill.size()==0){
        noPrev.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        recyclerList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else{
        noPrev.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        recyclerList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    h  = new Handler();
    r = () -> {
        BridgeInterface.GetBIlls getBIlls =
                new BillsRequest(getContext());
        getBIlls.request();
        h.postDelayed(r,5000);
    };
    r.run();
}


@Override
public void Bill(List<Bill> bills) {
    list_of_bill = bills;
    initRecycler();
}

public void initRecycler() {
    noPrev.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    recyclerList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    adapter = new BillRecyclerAdapter(list_of_bill);
    recyclerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
}
}
```

Here's the Interface Class

```
public interface BridgeInterface {

interface BillsResponse{
    void Bill(List<Bill> bills);
}

interface GetBIlls{
    void request();
}

}
```

BillRequest Class;:::

```
public class BillsRequest implements BridgeInterface.GetBIlls {

private Context context;

private final String url = "http://"+ 
AppSingleton.getInstance().getIP_ADDRESS()
        +"/waterdistrict/bills.php";
private Gson gson;

public BillsRequest(Context context ) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void request() {
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            response -> {
                gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                List<BillResponse> bill_response =
                        Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(response, 
 BillResponse.class));
                Log.d("Check", "Levl 2");
                Home.getInstance().Bill(bill_response.get(0).getBills());
            }, error -> {
        Log.d("Error", error.toString());
    });

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    queue.add(request);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the `Bill()` method is called between `onCreateView()` and `onDestroyView()`? By the way, don't forget about binding reset when working with fragments (http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife#reset).

Comment: You should unbind your widgets in `onDestroyView()` (follow the link, there's an example).

Comment: @MaximBlumental: In my onRusume() method, when the  getBIlls.request() is called it will start a web request and when its done, Bill() method will be triggered.

Comment: One more observation: your fragment implements `BridgeInterface.BillsResponse` and acts as a listener if I got it right. But you do not set the listener to the request. Perhaps your forgot something like `getBIlls.setBillsResponse(Home.this)`.

Comment: @MaximBlumental: It does not have a setter. that interface(BridgeInterface.GetBIlls) is from the same interface class with BridgeInterface.BillsResponse... I called BridgeInterface.BillsResponse.Bill(List<Bill> bills) with this line :   Home.getInstance().Bill(bill_response.get(0).getBills());